# Поиск с PDO и с помощью Prepard Statements

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Допустим, я хочу сделать поиск. Этот код ищет 2 или 3 заданых слова одновременно, это хорошо, так и задумано.

Вопрос, как сделать этот поиск через `Prepared Statements` и `bindParam` или `bindValue` чтобы недопустить SQL инъекции. Я понимаю стандарт кода на PHP.NET-prepare и прочие. Всё, что я пробовал, не дало результата. Я уверен что проблема находится в переменной `$sql_where_string`, но как эту всю информацию передать в SELECT Statement? Код, так как он щас есть, работает. Ну это конечно не серьёзно.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchword); $i++) {

                    if (!empty($searchword[$i])) {

                        $sql_where_string .= "name1 LIKE '%".$searchword[$i]."%' 
                                            OR name2 LIKE '%".$searchword[$i]."%' 
                                            OR столб1 LIKE '%".$searchword[$i]."%' 
                                            OR столб2 LIKE '%".$searchword[$i]."%' 
                                            OR столб3 LIKE '%".$searchword[$i]."%' 
                                            OR столб4 LIKE '%".$ssearchword[$i]."%'";

            if($i < (sizeof($searchword) -1)) {

                            $sql_where_string .= " OR ";
              }
             }
            }

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name1, name2, name3, name4 FROM table WHERE '. $sql_where_string. ' ORDER BY ' . $orderby_1);
        } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name1 name2, name3, name3 FROM table ORDER BY " . $orderby_1);

        $stmt->execute();

        foreach($stmt as $row){

               echo "и прочие";
          }
```

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where